# SQL custom sort order for Exam Questions

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting

For a project I am currently working on I need to create a list of questions that are sorted in a particular order and I'm currently not sure how to do that in SQL and I'm hoping someone might be able to help.

I have a list of questions and I want to be able to sort them by order of difficulty (Medium, Easy, Hard) but the twist is that if we have a list of 6 questions with 2 in each difficulty level then the order should look like

```
Medium,
Easy,
Hard,
Medium,
Easy,
Hard
```

If we have eight questions broken down into:

```
Easy x 3
Medium x 3
Hard x 2
```

They need to appear like:

```
Medium,
Easy,
Hard
Medium,
Easy,
Hard
Medium,
Easy
```

I'm starting to think that this is probably more likely the job of the PHP rather than SQL but if anyone has any advice I would appreciate it.

Edit: using MySQL/PHP

Thanks,
Colin

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a row-number system. If you're using MSSQL you can use `ROW_NUMBER`, you mentioned using PHP so you're probably using MySQL, I'm not familiar with MySQL enough to give a solution for that platform.

First we `PARTITION` the data by difficulty and assign their own ROW_NUMBER, then we order by this generated row-number and then by difficulty, like so:

```
CREATE TABLE Questions (
    QuestionData ...,
    Difficulty nvarchar(10)
)

SELECT
    QuestionData,
    Difficulty,
    (
        CASE
            WHEN Difficulty = 'Medium' THEN 1
            WHEN Difficulty = 'Easy'   THEN 2
            ELSE                            3
        END
    ) AS DifficultyInt,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Difficulty ORDER BY QuestionData ) AS RowNumber
FROM
    Questions
ORDER BY
    DifficultyInt
```

Comment: My apologies I should have mentioned that I was using MySQL... When I tried your sqlfiddle on MySQL it errored but maybe I use the same concept

Answer (score 0):

I made a [SQLFiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5facb/5) that uses Row_Number in SQl Server.

```
SELECT DIFFICULTY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DIFFICULTY ORDER BY DIFFICULTY) AS RN
FROM TABLE1  
ORDER BY CASE DIFFICULTY WHEN 'MEDIUM' THEN 1 
                         WHEN 'EASY' THEN 2 
                         WHEN 'HARD' THEN 3 END, RN
```

Comment: My apologies for not mentioning that I am using MySQL

Comment: Just noticed when playing with the SQLFiddle that the ordering should have been RN first then the case statement to get the correct order (just in case someone else is looking at this answer).

`SELECT DIFFICULTY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY DIFFICULTY ORDER BY DIFFICULTY) AS RN
    FROM TABLE1  
    ORDER BY RN, CASE DIFFICULTY WHEN 'MEDIUM' THEN 1 
                             WHEN 'EASY' THEN 2 
                             WHEN 'HARD' THEN 3 END`

Thanks @Hannover Fist

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestions... From your answers for MSSQL I've been able to do a bit of research and come up with a solution for MySQL that I think should fit the bill.

```
SELECT    DIFFICULTY,
          @num := if(@type = DIFFICULTY, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
          @type := DIFFICULTY as dummy
FROM      Table1 t
ORDER BY  row_number, CASE DIFFICULTY WHEN 'MEDIUM' THEN 1 
                         WHEN 'EASY' THEN 2 
                         WHEN 'HARD' THEN 3 END
```

See the [SQL Fiddle example](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/5facb/15/0)